# Query documents in MongoDB by object matching

Tags: java, mongodb

How can I find the document that contains the a given JSON object?

Example:

suppose that in the database `test` there is a document like this:

```
{
  "identification": {
    "componentId": "3a4f6199-6141-4179-ac5f-f1bbcf627bb2",
    "componentType": "PivotTable",
    "dataDate": "2016-06-15T15:29:51.139+0200",
    "dataType": "PTF",
    "properties": {
      "contextId": "0329fe70-92f0-4b60-b3c2-79377adb8f95",
      "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
    }
  },
  "viewData": {
    "lineGroups": []
  }
}
```

Now given only the `identification` part of the document with partial keys set with value:

```
{
    "componentType": "PivotTable",
    "properties": {
      "tags": ["tag1"]
    }
}
```

Since the above document's identification part is matching the given identification, then that document should be returned.

If I do `db.test.find({identification: {/*the given identification segment*/}})`, mongodb will compare directly the identification part by checking exactly every entry in the document. In this case that document will not be returned.

Is there a way in mongodb query language that allows me to do this in relatively straight forward or easy way? Or I have to parse the entries in Identification object recursively in order to construct a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo will try to match WHOLE properties subdocument,
so in this case we will have to supply 1:1 document.

The way you could try to get this working is unwind every element and add it to query filter section.

```
{
    "componentType": "PivotTable",
    "properties.tags": {$in:["tag1"]}    
}
```

Comment: So in this way I still need to construct a query string by parsing the entries in the subdocument. No more easy way? Since when the subdocuement structure gets complex(containing another subdocument with different types of values), constructing the query gets not that easy.

Comment: @qingl97  If my answer helped you please accept it see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer